# Issue using textscan() on Octave 4.0.3 (3 million lines / 250 MB file)

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to rewrite a piece of MATLAB code so it can run using Octave, but I've found some trouble using the textscan() function.

Original Code (MATLAB):

```
function data = import_file(filename, startRow, endRow)

delimiter = ' ';
if nargin<=2
    startRow = 3;
    endRow = inf;
end

formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%*s%[^\n\r]';

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);
    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow(block)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    for col=1:length(dataArray)
        dataArray{col} = [dataArray{col};dataArrayBlock{col}];
    end
end

fclose(fileID);

data = [dataArray{1:end-1}];

end
```

Error:

```
error: strread: %q, %c, %[] or bit width format specifier
s are not supported yet.
error: called from
     strread at line 329 column 7
     textscan at line 321 column 8
     import_file at line 13 column 15
     main at line 52 column 22
```

Sample Data:

```
# U  POINT_DATA 3711396
#  x  y  z  U_x  U_y  U_z  
739263.5 9363820 172.809998 -5.34212399 -0.0408997531 0.0736143066
739263.5 9363789 172.979996 -5.34212399 -0.0408997531 0.0736143066
739294.312 9363820 172.449997 -5.34212399 -0.0408997531 0.0736143066
739294.312 9363789 173.710007 -5.34212399 -0.0408997531 0.0736143066
739325.125 9363820 170.699997 -5.248474 -0.00403332808 0.041700209
739325.125 9363789 172.350006 -5.37227834 -0.0307070923 0.0492642202
739355.938 9363820 168.690002 -5.248474 -0.00403332808 0.041700209
739355.938 9363789 170.5 -5.37227834 -0.0307070923 0.0492642202
739386.75 9363820 169.110001 -5.248474 -0.00403332808 0.041700209
739386.75 9363789 170.839996 -5.37227834 -0.0307070923 0.0492642202
739417.562 9363820 170.789993 -5.248474 -0.00403332808 0.041700209
739417.562 9363789 171.820007 -5.37227834 -0.0307070923 0.0492642202
```

I've already tried using other functions, such as dlmread(), load() and even fgetl() to do the job, but it takes too much time compared to the 8s it used to take on MATLAB.

Replacing the formatSpec with '%f%f%f%f%f%f' didn't work either.

The file contains 3711396 lines and 250 MB of data divided in six columns of data.

Can you help me adapting the code?

Comment: Just using `load` should be the fastest way to read your data in Octave. Have you tried `data=load(filename)(startRow:endRow,:);`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to go through your code and found out that there were two things preventing it from running.

The first was the use of `%[^\n\r]` in your formatSpec

The second was the use of the 'ReturnOnError' name/value pair.

Both of these features are not yet supported in Octave.

I was able to successfully import the Sample Data that you provided using the following modified code:

```
function data = import_file(filename, startRow, endRow)

if nargin<=2
    startRow = 3;
    endRow = inf;
end

formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f';
% Corrected formatSpec to import 6 consecutive floats 

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1,...
    'EmptyValue' ,NaN,...
    'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1); 
% Removed 'ReturnOnError' as it is not yet implimented in Octave.

for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);

    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec,...
        endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1,...
        'EmptyValue' ,NaN,...
        'HeaderLines', startRow(block)-1);

    for col=1:length(dataArray)
        dataArray{col} = [dataArray{col};dataArrayBlock{col}];
    end
end

fclose(fileID);

data = [dataArray{1:end}]; 
%Changed 'end-1' to 'end' to include last column.

end
```